# Mutual info between continuous and discrete variables from numerical data

Tags: distributions, random-variable, conditional-probability, mutual-information

I am looking for references/measures to estimate the mutual information between a continuous (C) and discrete (D) variable, given a real-world (i.e. finite sample) data set. C is uniformly distributed between Cmin and Cmax, and D is a positive integer whose distribution depends on the value of C (e.g., a poisson distribution). Any suggestions (methods based on binning over the data set, or independent of binning) are welcome.

Comment: Define mutual information.

Comment: A measure of statistical (in)dependence between two random variables. Standard definition.

Comment: I think you are looking for a chi square test, where you would bin your countinuous variable into a numbe of bins. How you would bin it depends, if you have some domain knowledge you can use it to create sensible intervals, otherwise equal size or quantile intervals.